# How can I analyze .diagsession file from IE's developer tools?

Tags: microsoft-excel, internet-explorer

I am troubleshooting some issues with HTTP traffic and using the "UI Responsiveness" developer tool in Internet Explorer 11 to collect data.

I know that I can save these files off and re-open them later using IE, but what I'd really like is a way to export the data for analysis in Excel.

Are there any tools or tricks to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Either use Microsoft Visual Studio (the community edition is enough), or [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview).

Answer (score 0):

Change the file to a .zip extension.. You will see some folders that contain ETL files.  You can open those with the Microsoft Event Viewer Snap In, however they aren't very useful.

Try http://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=216 .. It might be a decent tool to try.

Good luck!

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=216 is deprecated page. Can you please show us the valid page URL?